# RESTful: how to dynamically extend an API path's (or available resources)?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I've had a nice 'ride' with RESTful technology. I am using a Hello.java resource like this:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    ... /* GET/PUT/POST */
}
```

With this I can access my resource with the path `http://my.host/res/hello` . I want to 'ride' RESTful even harder. Having this one resource path is a bit boring.

**PROBLEM**

I would like to have a dynamically created resources like this:

- `http://my.host/res/hello`
- `http://my.host/res/hello/1`
- `http://my.host/res/hello/2`
- ...
- `http://my.host/res/hello/999`

It doesn't make sense to create a .java resource for every `@Path("/hello/1") ... @Path("/hello/999")`. Right? Probably this list of sub-resources could be even bigger or dynamically change in time. What is the solution for that?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check out Spring MVC

Comment: I am using JAX-RS/Jersey now. Is this 'Spring MVC' added over Jersey, or this is more like competition for Jersey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `@Path` annotation on methods inside your Resource class.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    ... /* GET/PUT/POST */

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public String myMethod(@PathParam("id") String id) {...}
}
```

The paths will be concatenated so it will match `/hello/13`. The `{id}` is a placeholder for the actual value entered, which can be retrieved with `@PathParam`. In the previous URI, the String `id` will have the value `13`.

Comment: Can I go even further and make Path("{id}/{subid}") with this approach?

Comment: @flyer You sure can. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-path-uri-matching-example/)'s an example.

Answer (score 7):

You will have to use PathParam feature for REST URI. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html

```
    @Path("/hello/{id}")
    public class Hello {

    }
```

Comment: How do we access the {id} value on the class methods?

Comment: Found it! https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter5/path_param.html